# Chains of Well-ordered sets

Tags: order-theory

Let $\{X_i\mid i\in I\}$ be a chain of sets and $\{R_i\mid i\in I\}$ be the corresponding chain of relations such, $R_i$ well orders $X_i$. Show that $\bigcup_{i\in I}R_i$ well orders $\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i$, that is for any $Y\subset\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i$, there is a $y'\in Y$ such that  $(y',y)\bigcup_{i\in I}R_i$, for all $y\in Y$. Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Let $I=\mathbb Z$, $X_i=\{\,k\in\mathbb Z\mid k+i>0\,\}$, $R_i$ the standard order on $X_i$ (which is a well-order as $X_i$ is just a translated $\mathbb N$). Then $\bigcup R_i$ is just the standard order on $\bigcup X_i=\mathbb Z$ and is not a well-order.

Comment: Yes, you are right but I was reading some notes where the question came, up, this is the selected passage:

Comment: Yes, I follow you but I was reading some notes where the question came up, this is the selected passage: "Given $X\neq\emptyset$, let $\mathcal{Q}$ be the collection of all pairs $(Y,R)$ such that $Y\subset X$ and $R$ is a well ordering of $Y$ , i.e. R  is a total order
satisfying the DCC. Order $\mathcal{Q}$ by $(Y,R)\subset (Z,S)$ iff $Y\subset Z$ and $R\subset S$. In order
to apply Zorn's Lemma, check that if $\{(Y_i,R_i):i\in I\}$, is a chain in $\mathcal{Q}$, then $(\cup Y_i, \cup R_i)\in \mathcal{Q}$. Did they make a mistake or am I missing something and not getting it? Thanks